# Retrieve data from firebase database to nested dictionary

Tags: json, firebase, dictionary, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

I'm having a lots of problems trying to retrieve data from the firebase database and moving that data to a unity dictionary.

So I would like to do this, to just retrieve the data one time and then place all the data to a dictionary, the problem is that I can't find the way to do it if the dictionary is a nested dictionary.

This is how my database looks like (simplified):

```
    {"questions": {
    "group1": {
        "id_1": {
          "Question": "question one",
          "A": "answer1"
        },
        "id_2": {
          "Question": "question two",
          "A": "answer2"
        }
      }
  }
    }
```

So in my code I do the following:

```
public void RetrievePreguntesJson()
{
    string group = "group1"
    questions_ref.Child(group).GetValueAsync().ContinueWith(task => {
        if (task.IsFaulted)
        {
            Debug.LogError("Error Getting Info from user database");
        }
        else if (task.IsCompleted)
        {
            DataSnapshot snapshot = task.Result;
            myDictionary = snapshot.Value as Dictionary<string, object>;
            dataReady();
        }
    });
}
```

So the problem is that I can't get any value.
I would like to do something like `myDictionary["id_1"]["Question"]` and get the value "question one". Or `myDictionary["id_1"].Question` and get the value "question one".

I already tried the following:
- Create a Class questions like this:

```
public class Questions
{
    public string id;
    public string Question;
    public string Answer;

    public Questions(string id, string Question, string Answer)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.Question = Question;
        this.Answer = Answer;
    }
}
```

And use the following code instead of `"userInfoDictionary = snapshot.Value as Dictionary<string, object>;"`

Use:

```
Questions ClassObjectName = JsonUtility.FromJson<Questions>(snapshot.GetRawJsonValue());
```

But it didn't work either.

Also tried:

```
"userInfoDictionary = snapshot.Value as Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, object>>;"
```

But it won't work either.

Can anyone help me please?

"EDIT"

This is my json:

```
{"questions": {
    "group1": {
        "id_1": {
          "Question": "question one",
          "A": "answer1"
        },
        "id_2": {
          "Question": "question two",
          "A": "answer2"
        }
      }
  }
    }
```

And this are the objects:

```
[System.Serializable]
public class Group1
{
    public QuestionsId group1;
}
[System.Serializable]
public class QuestionsId
{
    public Questions id;
}
[System.Serializable]
public class Questions
{
    public string Question;
    public string A;
}
```

I'm deserializing the Json with:

```
Group1 ClassObjectName = JsonUtility.FromJson<Group1>(snapshot.GetRawJsonValue());
```

I would like to be able to have a result calling the values like this:
`myDictionary["id_1"].Question`
`myDictionary["id_1"]["Question"]`

I'm using the object and the Json utility now, but if there is anyway to use a unity dictionary to have the result that I would like to have it is also ok for me. For example: `"userInfoDictionary = snapshot.Value as Dictionary<string, object>;"`

Does anyone knows how to help me please?

Comment: Your object does not match your json .Use [this](http://json2csharp.com/) to generate the proper objects to de-serialize your class with then read the duplicate for how to de-serialize it. If you run into problem, read the troubleshooting section from the duplicate. Finally, you can edit this question with your new code and let me know if it's now working for you.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer.
It isn't exactly working, as effectively json2csharp give me the objects that this concrete json needs. But what is I have an undefined number of "group" key and undefined number of "id_" key?
json2csharp gives to me something like this:
public class Id1
{public string Question { get; set; }
public string A { get; set; }
}
public class Id2
{public string Question { get; set; }
public string A { get; set; }}
public class Group1
{public Id1 id_1 { get; set; }
public Id2 id_2 { get; set; }}
public class RootObject
{
public Group1 group1 { get; set; }
}

Comment: Edit your question then add "EDIT" followed by your new code. Don't post code in the comment section. Shoe  your new object and how you're de-serializing them. Finally, make sure to read the troubleshooting section from the duplicate. You didn't. If you did, you wouldn't have `{ get; set; }`. Also, if you've read it `[Serializable]` would be on top of each class you generated.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't find the troubleshooting section... is it in this page? http://json2csharp.com/#
or you talking about this one? https://app.quicktype.io/#l=cs&r=json2csharp

Comment: I marked this question as a duplicate. Refresh the page and look at your question. It will tell you that the question has been closed and will point to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36239705/serialize-and-deserialize-json-and-json-array-in-unity) question. That's what you should be looking at

Comment: Ok, I see the thing with the [System.Serializable] and the Set, Get... But I still have the same problem with the undefined numbers of groups or ids, I can't see the duplication of my question with the one you linked me to. 
Can you reopen the question I made as I still have the problem?? 
Thanks.

Comment: A question is only re-opened if you tired what's in the duplicate and it's not working. So far you haven't shown that. *You have to edit your question show the updated objects, the new you'r using to de-serialize the json and your new error or issue*

Comment: Ok it is now edited with what I have after read the other post. I'm still having the problem that I can't read the ids.

Comment: In your edit, you also have to show how you're de-serializing the json. You haven't done so.  The duplicate shows how to do this with the JsonUtility API. Also, you keep changing your json on each update and I don't know why. Your current json doesn't even match the objects in your edit. You have to re-generate the objects again to match your json. Update your question again after that.

Comment: Ok I already edited the question again,  with all what I have, so please, my question is not about the jsonUtility, it is also useful for me if there is another way to use the snapshot that firebase returns, for example converting it to a unity dictionary. So can you please open again the question?, so any other person who wants to help can join to this thread. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone has the same problem. 
What I found to do what I was looking for, is that JsonUtility from unity can't do it because it just work with a knowing keys as you have always to create your objects as a classes in unity. 
So, if for example my json has the "id_3" key it will not work because my objects only have "id_1" and "id_2". The only way to be able to create an undefined numbers of Ids is making them an arrays (which I don't want in this case) because it will make you call the dictionary something like this: `myDictionary[0]["Question"]`
But anyway, just if someone needs it, the Json should be like this to work with JsonUtility (setting the Ids as an array):

```
{"questions": {
    "group1": [
               {
                 "Question": "question one",
                 "A": "answer1"
               },
               {
                 "Question": "question two",
                 "A": "answer2"
               }
              ]
          }
 }
```

Well, as this isn't what I was looking for, the easiest way I found to do it is using the SimpleJson library which does exactly what I expected and it is super easy to use, without needed to create your own objects in unity.
With a normal Json file coming from the snapshot of the firebase:

```
{"questions": {
        "group1": {
            "id_1": {
              "Question": "question one",
              "A": "answer1"
            },
            "id_2": {
              "Question": "question two",
              "A": "answer2"
            }
          }
       }
     }
```

You just have to do the following:

```
var N = JSON.Parse(snapshot.GetRawJsonValue());
Debug.Log("N---> " + N["id_1"].ToString());
```

So it does exactly what I expected.
The bad thing here is that this is an external library, so it could have some problems in unity for example trying to use syncVars with this data.

Comment: So `snapshot` is just the DocumentSnapshot retrieved form the query. But where is that `GetRawJsonValue()` from exactly? are you using a different library or something?

Comment: Sorry Tarek, but this post is very old, and I don’t really remember how I was using it.

Comment: ah yes I realize it's quite old, but I am stuck in the same issue and thought that it was worth a shot to ask haha. Thank you for the reply anyway :)